# Searching for the minimum value in a list of tuple?

Tags: python

I have this function where it takes in a list of tuples as it's parameter, I'm trying to return the oldest person but in order to do that I need to find the minimum value of the age im just having trouble with this since it's in a list of tuple. I tried to use the min() function but it didn't work out.

```
def oldest_person(people: list):
    new_list = []
    age = 1977
    for persons in people:
        if persons[1] == age:
            new_list.append(persons[0])    
      
    return new_list


p1 = ("Adam", 1977)
p2 = ("Ellen", 1985)
p3 = ("Mary", 1995)
p4 = ("Ernest", 1997)
people = [p1, p2, p3, p4]
print(oldest_person(people))
```

Comment: The `min()` and `max()` functions take an optional function argument, which you can use to tell the `min()` and `max()` functions what value to use when making comparisons: `min(people, key=lambda p: p[1])`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`min`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min), with a key function that looks at the second element of the tuples. Then simply select the first element of the returned tuple:

```
p1 = ("Adam", 1977)
p2 = ("Ellen", 1985)
p3 = ("Mary", 1995)
p4 = ("Ernest", 1997)
people = [p1, p2, p3, p4]
oldest_person = min(people, key=lambda p:p[1])[0]
```

Output:

```
Adam
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use min/max functions or sort the people and access the first person (oldest) or the last person (youngest).

```
sorted_people = sorted(people, key=lambda person: person[1])
oldest = sorted_people[0]
youngest = sorted_people[-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom comparator to sort the list `people` according to the birthyear. Something like this should work:

```
from functools import cmp_to_key
p1 = ("Adam", 1977)
p2 = ("Ellen", 1985)
p3 = ("Mary", 1995)
p4 = ("Ernest", 1997)
people = [p1, p2, p3, p4]

# here, you sort the list by comparing the ages.
sorted(people, key=cmp_to_key(lambda person1, person2: person1[1] - person2[1]))

print("Olderst person is", people[0][0], "who was born",  people[0][1])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Python's "min" function and "itemgetter" to find the minimum value in the second index of the tuples, then return the first element to get the name.

```
from operator import itemgetter

def oldest_person(people):
    return min(people, key=itemgetter(1))[0]

p1 = ("Adam", 1977)
p2 = ("Ellen", 1985)
p3 = ("Mary", 1995)
p4 = ("Ernest", 1997)
people = [p1, p2, p3, p4]

print(oldest_person(people)) # expected output: Adam
```

Answer (score 0):

you hard coded the oldest person `age` and checking for the same `age` in the list. So, it only returns the `person` with the `age` you coded.

My solution is not optimal but might work perhaps.

```
def oldest_person(people):
    age = [person[1] for person in people]
    age.sort()
    new_list = []
    for i in range(len(people)):
        if age[i] == people[i][1]:
            new_list.append(people[i][0])
    print(new_list)

p1 = ("Adam", 1977)
p2 = ("Ellen", 1985)
p3 = ("Mary", 1995)
p4 = ("Ernest", 1997)
people = [p1, p2, p3, p4]
oldest_person(people)
```

Output:

```
['Adam', 'Ellen', 'Mary', 'Ernest']
```